# ALAssetsLibrary loading a single photo from ALAssetsGroupAll

Tags: ios

I'm trying to build a custom image picker similar to `iOS` 7's photos app. I was able to get it to pick a photo from the Camera Roll (`ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos`) but I'm struggling to load a single image from another album - one which I've created for testing purposes.

Here's the code I'm using to load a photo from the camera roll:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
    numberOfPhotos = [group numberOfAssets];

    [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:index] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {


                             if (alAsset) {

                                 ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
                                 UIImage *lastImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]];


                             }

                         }];

}
                     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error2) {


                     }];
```

I tried to replace the `ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos` with `ALAssetsGroupAll` but it's returning the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   'indexSet count or lastIndex must not exceed -numberOfAssets'

Comment: How do you define `index`?

Comment: reecon Index is the number of the photo I'm trying to pick based on it's thumbnail position in a table view cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are enumerating all folders in the library and trying to get a photo out of each folder. This is wrong. First you have to get your folder.

```
__block ALAssetsGroup* folder;
NSString *yourFolderName = ...;

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                             usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
{
      if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:yourFolderName]) 
      {
          folder = group;
      }
}
                           failureBlock:^(NSError* error) 
{
    // Error handling.    
}];
```

Then, get an image from the folder:

```
[group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:index] 
                        options:0 
                     usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) 
{
     if (alAsset) 
     {
         ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
         UIImage *lastImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]];
     }
}];
```

But make sure the `index` is correct.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification reecon. Much appreciated. Once you get to folder = group, how do I pick, for example photo number 3 in the album?